# What is the new equivalent of sensord?

Tags: 18.04, temperature, system-monitor, sensors, lm-sensors

> Sensord is a daemon that can be used to periodically log sensor readings from hardware health-monitoring chips to syslog(3) or a round-robin database (RRD) and to alert when a sensor alarm is signalled; for example, if a fan fails, a temperature limit is exceeded, etc.

https://linux.die.net/man/8/sensord

`sensord` does not seem to be available since Ubuntu 18.04.  Given that it's quite useful to periodically log sensor info to syslog for crash diagnosis etc., is there a new equivalent of `sensord` available on Ubuntu 18.04 and later?

Comment: sensord should be included in the lm_sensors package, which is included in the [Universe repo since Ubuntu 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lm-sensors)

Comment: Hmm it's odd, because on Arch sensord is included, but maybe not on Ubuntu. I might stand corrected. :-|

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 it is also missing. It's not in `lm-sensors` and I have no files I can `locate` with `sensord` in the name. Additionally a check with `apt-file` shows references from SELinux-related packages to `sensord` _profiles_ but no actual `sensord` anymore.

Comment: Seems to be gone still in Ubuntu 22.04. This returns nothing: `dpkg -L lm-sensors | grep sensord`.